# jquery - Check specific inputs for empty value and add class to ONLY those inputs that are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form that has input fields that are required, I point this out with made up class name.
I have piece of code that kind of works. If I focus on required input and then press submit, that input will become red, if empty (which I want). But it only works only on one at a time and if I have focus on the input.

My code is as follows:

```
function checkIfEmpty(){
    $('#register-form input.gv-form-required').blur(function(){
        if( !$(this).val()){
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I am almost certain that the `blur()` method is not suitable for my situation.
So help a man out here, please.

Comment: Can you post full code?

Comment: Try `.filter()` instead of `.blur()`

Comment: No need to post "full" code. Like I cleared above that code is executed when you press submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You have to use `.each()` to check every input inside form and put `removeClass` in `else` condition.

```
function checkIfEmpty(){
    var empty = false;
    $('#register-form input.gv-form-required').each(function(){
        if($(this).val().trim()==""){
            empty = true;
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
        }else{
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");
        }
    });
    return empty;
}
```

Comment: Marvellous! And here I was thinking about complex manual foreach loops :) Unfortunately this code applies ´.has-error´ to the first found empty field and not all found empty fields. Sorry I make this more complicated.

Comment: This return true solves the "applied to all" problem but when return false is used the each loop stops to work and applies removeClass only to one empty error field. It's like `return false` escapes somehow.

Comment: I think we don't need to return anything from each loop, lets remove it.

Comment: But my code checks if `checkIfEmpty === false` and sends a post request via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

The `blur` event indeed doesn't seem right in your situation. What I would do is that I would itterate through each field and checked whether it is filled or not. If it is, remove (if any) `has-error` class. If it isn't filled, give it the `has-error` class

```
function checkIfEmpty(){
    $('#register-form input.gv-form-required').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() === ""){
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
        }else{
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the following:

```
function checkIfEmpty(){
   $('#register-form input.gv-form-required').each(function(){
       if( !$(this).is(':empty')){
           $(this).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
       }else{
           $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try
 in else condition

```
$(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");
```

### js code

```
      if( !$(this).val()){
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");

        }else{
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");

        }
```